# php foreach inside for statement problems

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Sorry if this has been asked before however I am having trouble finding the answer to my problem.

I am trying to build a calendar system and schedule system for my web application in PHP and having difficulty with one particular area.

I have a "for" statement where it will draw up the times of the day starting at 12:00AM and finishing at 11:30PM

Inside this for loop, I have a foreach which i want to echo out the objects in an array that match a particular time.

Everything I have tried which includes using for,while and foreach statements don't show what I am after which is the events lining up next to the time.

here is my code

```
<?php
$tStart = strtotime($start_time);
$tEnd = strtotime($end_time);
$tNow = $tStart;

while($items = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $events[] = $items;
}

for($tNow=$tStart; $tNow<$tEnd; $tNow=strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow)){
    // Time to color the rows to make it easier to read
    if(!isset($day_row)){
        $day_row = "0";
    }
    if(isset($day_row) && $day_row >= "2"){
        $day_row--;
    }
    else{ $day_row++; 
    }

    //This bit draws the first column.
    echo "<tr><td class=\"day_row".$day_row."\" width=\"70px\">".date("h:i A",$tNow)."</td>";

    // MySQL stuff is now here
    foreach($events as $e => $item){
        if($item->apnt_start == $tnow){
            $rowspan = ((strtotime($item->apnt_finish)-strtotime($item->apnt_start))/"1800");
            echo "<td class=\"day_row_apnt\" rowspan=\"$rowspan\">".$item->apnt_start."-".$item->apnt_finish." ".$item->apnt_brief."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

at present i am given a page with 
12:00 AM
12:30 AM
01:00 AM
01:30 AM
02:00 AM
02:30 AM
03:00 AM
03:30 AM
04:00 AM
04:30 AM
05:00 AM
05:30 AM

Next to the time I want the appointment with matching time.

I am trying to achieve something similar to http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/
I can't use their system however as I can't integrate it properly and I have tried looking at their code and it seems to be pointing at many files and i am having trouble trying to understand the function i am after.

Please let me know if this is not clear enough and will try to explain further.

Comment: What does your code result in, and how does it differ from what you're looking for?

Comment: with the if statement in place under the foreach loop nothing appears.
it seems that $tNow will stay on 12:00AM and won't go forward.

how do i get the $tNow to go forward so that the foreach will eventually come true if there is an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank everyone that provided advice on this issue, I have finally got it working with added another variable and using a method of storing an array in an array.

The final code looks like

```
<?php
    $tStart = strtotime($start_time);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end_time);
    $tNow = $tStart;
    $events = array();
    $eas = "0"; // eas stands for Event Array Start. this will be used to cycle through the events in the array.
    while($items = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $events[] = $items;
    }

    for($tNow=$tStart; $tNow<$tEnd; $tNow=strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow)){
        // Time to color the rows to make it easier to read
            if(!isset($day_row)){
                $day_row = "0";
            }
            if(isset($day_row) && $day_row >= "2"){
                $day_row--;
            }
            else{ $day_row++; 
            }

            //This bit draws the first column.
            echo "<tr><td class=\"day_row".$day_row."\" width=\"70px\">".date("h:i A",$tNow)."</td>";
        if(strtotime($events[$eas]['apnt_start']) == $tNow) {     
                $rowspan = ((strtotime($events[$eas]['apnt_finish'])-strtotime($events[$eas]['apnt_start']))/"1800");
                echo "<td class=\"day_row_apnt\" rowspan=\"$rowspan\" >".$events[$eas]['apnt_start']."-".$events[$eas]['apnt_finish']." ".$events[$eas]['apnt_brief']."</td></tr>";
                $eas++;
           }
            else{
                echo "<td class=\"day_row".$day_row."\"></td>";
            }
        } //end for
?>
```

By using the variable $eas I was able to then control which number it would start at by setting it to 0 initially and then when it found an entry with a matching time it went through the if statement where at the end of the if statement it was given $eas++ to increment.

This then proved that if there was no appointment the $eas would not run and it would not increment thus remaining on the last incremented $eas.

Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and set value for variables below:

```
$start_time = "09:00 AM";
$end_time = "11:30 PM";
```

Also you need to add query and database connection (above `while($items = mysql_fetch_object($result)){` statement):

```
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
```

**EDIT:**
You should use while mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_object. 
Replace

```
while($items = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
```

with

```
while($items = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Delete: `$events[] = $items;`

Ensure your while statement above ends after all code is executed (code you listed in your question) - closing bracket `}`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have set the $start_time & $end_time in another file. I have also got a generic mysql.php which defines the connection information your talking about.
I am getting the $items populated with information from mysql however my most recent issue where the information wouldn't match the time it was scheduled for.

Comment: So what is the problem than? Is this about the HTML output; trying to put it in the table or something?

Comment: doing a print_r($events) gives the following
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [apnt_id] => 6 [apnt_person] => 3 [apnt_date] => 2012-11-17 [apnt_start] => 00:00 [apnt_finish] => 00:30 [apnt_brief] => test 3 [apnt_description] => testing description 3 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [apnt_id] => 4 [apnt_person] => 3 [apnt_date] => 2012-11-17 [apnt_start] => 08:30 [apnt_finish] => 09:00 [apnt_brief] => test 1 [apnt_description] => testing description 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [apnt_id] => 5 [apnt_person] => 3 [apnt_date] => 2012-11-17 [apnt_start] => 12:00 

I can't fit the entire array details in.

Comment: the problem is that the foreach statement is constantly getting a $tNow value of 12:00AM which i would like it to go up so that it would eventually this statement will be true $item->apnt_start == $tnow)

Comment: See my edit answer; feel free to post your database table (export it from MySQL) so we could fully test it :-) Please avoid posting any private data you might have in data table...

Comment: when i tried your edit. it seemed to have repeated the times from 12AM to 12AM multiple times?
e.g 12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Comment: fields in table are:
apnt_id
apnt_person
apnt_date
apnt_start
apnt_finish
apnt_brief
apnt_description

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this should work for you.

```
<?php
    $tStart = strtotime($start_time);
    $tEnd = strtotime($end_time);
    $tNow = $tStart;

    echo '<table>';

    while($events = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        for($tNow=$tStart; $tNow<$tEnd; $tNow=strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow)){
        // Time to color the rows to make it easier to read
            if(!isset($day_row)){
                $day_row = "0";
            }
            if(isset($day_row) && $day_row >= "2"){
                $day_row--;
            }
            else{ $day_row++; 
            }

            //This bit draws the first column.
            echo "<tr><td class=\"day_row".$day_row."\" width=\"70px\">".date("h:i A",$tNow)."</td>";
            if(strtotime($events['apnt_start']) == $tNow) {     
                $rowspan = ((strtotime($events->apnt_finish)-strtotime($events->apnt_start))/"1800");
                echo "<td class=\"day_row_apnt\" rowspan=\"$rowspan\">".$events->apnt_start."-".$events->apnt_finish." ".$events->apnt_brief."</td></tr>";
            }
        } //end for
    } //end while
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Salih0vicX,
This is almost correct. The times are appearing where they should and so should the events, however.....
If i have three events for the day i am getting 12am to 12am three times with 1 event on each iteration of 12am to 12am.. I believe this is due to the while statement, is this correct?
is there a way to have it so that there is 1 iteration of 12am to 12am and the 3 events presented on that 1 iteration?